# My If-Else statement won't work although it's completely fine

Tags: javascript, html, json, if-statement, asynchronous

I posted a similar question, but it was taken down, put I still am very curious why something so trivial isn't working.
This is all of my html/javascript...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FoxBooks</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Foxbooks.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>FoxBooks</h1>
    <div id="course_selection">
        <h2>Find Your Textbooks:</h2>
        <p>Enter the CRN:</p>
        <select name="" id="CRN">
            <optgroup>
                <option value=""></option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn" />
    </div>
    <h1 id="Course_Info"></h1>
    <script>
```

My javascript starts here...

```
            selectCRN = document.getElementById("CRN").value;
            courseInfo = document.getElementById("Course_Info");
            button = document.getElementById("btn");


            async function getData(){
                //try this code, if it doesn't work...
                try{
                    let response = await fetch('https://davise7823.github.io/SD330/foxbooks.json'); // make a request to a JSON endpoint
                    let data = await response.json(); // parse the response as JSON

                    //populates the "CRN" selection list
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.courses.length; i++){
                        var x = document.getElementById("CRN");
                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.text = data.courses[i].CRN;
                        x.add(option);
                    }

                    //If one is selected display it in the course info element
```

This is where the if else statement fails

```
                    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        if(selectCRN == 12054){
                            courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[0].Name;
                        }else if (selectCRN == 10016) {
                            courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[1].Name;
                        }else if(selectCRN == 11011){
                            courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[2].Name;
                        }else if(selectCRN == 11338){
                            courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[3].Name;
                        }else if(selectCRN == 12005){
                            courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[4].Name;
                        }else if(selectCRN == 12017){
                            courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[5].Name;
                        }else if(selectCRN == 11452){
                            courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[6].Name;
                        }else if(selectCRN == 12904){
                            courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[7].Name;
```

If anything else is put in here it works, besides the if else statement.

```
                        }
                    });
                }
                //run this code to show any errors
                catch (error) {
                    console.error(error); // handle any errors
                }
            }
            getData();
```

My js ends here

```
    </script>
    <footer>
        <hr />
        <small>&copy Elijah D - 09/25/23</small>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `selectCRN = document.getElementById("CRN").value;` is executed once and has the value when it is executed, the value of `selectCRN` will never change no matter how many times you change the options, you've read the value before the options even exist ... try putting that line inside the click handler (also convert it to a number since you compare with numbers)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you so much! You've no idea how long I've tried to figure this out. It seemed obvious but I simply didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

Like @jaromanda-x points out in their comment, `element.value` needs to be evaluated inside the event listener, not before it.

```js
// Store the element, not its value, here
const selectCRNElement = document.getElementById("CRN");
const courseInfo = document.getElementById("Course_Info");
const button = document.getElementById("btn");


async function getData() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://davise7823.github.io/SD330/foxbooks.json');
    let data = await response.json(); 


    for (let i = 0; i < data.courses.length; i++) {
      var x = document.getElementById("CRN");
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = data.courses[i].CRN;
      x.add(option);
    }


    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // Get the value of the select element and convert it to an int for the comparisons on button click
      const selectCRN = parseInt(selectCRNElement.value)
      if (selectCRN == 12054) {
        courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[0].Name;
      } else if (selectCRN == 10016) {
        courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[1].Name;
      } else if (selectCRN == 11011) {
        courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[2].Name;
      } else if (selectCRN == 11338) {
        courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[3].Name;
      } else if (selectCRN == 12005) {
        courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[4].Name;
      } else if (selectCRN == 12017) {
        courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[5].Name;
      } else if (selectCRN == 11452) {
        courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[6].Name;
      } else if (selectCRN == 12904) {
        courseInfo.innerHTML = data.courses[7].Name;
      }
    });
  }
  //run this code to show any errors
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // handle any errors
  }
}
getData();
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>FoxBooks</h1>
  <div id="course_selection">
    <h2>Find Your Textbooks:</h2>
    <p>Enter the CRN:</p>
    <select name="" id="CRN">
      <optgroup>
        <option value=""></option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn" />
  </div>
  <h1 id="Course_Info"></h1>
  <footer>
    <hr />
    <small>&copy Elijah D - 09/25/23</small>
  </footer>
</body>
```